# Ajax POST with phonegap and php

Tags: php, ajax, cordova

I am developing an Android application and I want to store my data in the remote database. I have my index.html, jquery 1.9.1 and test.php.

I want to store the information you submit in index.html to test.php via ajax running my android application.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

PS: I tested my web application with wamp worked and I know that if you are not in the same domain does not work

Am trying something like this:

Index.html:

```
<form action="javascript:func();" >


    <div id="divSend" >
        <input type="button" value="Send" id="send" />
    </div>
    <div id="divMensagem">
        <textarea placeholder="type anything..." rows="6" name="sms" id="sms"></textarea>
    </div>

</form>
```

my file.js:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            $('#send').bind('click', function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var sms = $('#sms').val(); 
                var p = $.post( 'http://www.domain.com/test/test.php', { sms: sms } );

                p.done(function (data){
                    alert(data);
                });
           }); 
        });
```

my index.php:

```
<php
          $sms = $_POST['sms'];

           echo $sms;
?>
```

Comment: which part doesnt work?

Comment: @MichaelKunst in file.js... it doesn't return nothing inside android emulator